# Does logarithm function satisfy polynomial growth condition?

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I am trying to solve the recurrence $$T(n) = 5T(\sqrt{n}) + \log\log n$$ Assuming $n =2^m, m \in \mathbb{N}$, I got- $$S(m)= 5S\bigg(\frac{m}{2}\bigg) + \log m$$

I used the Akra-Bazzi method to solve it. To use the method I justified that $\log$ satisfies polynomial growth condition as for all $\Phi \geq 1$, we can choose constant $d = \Phi$, such that
$$\frac{\log n}{d} \leq \log(\Psi \cdot n) \leq d \log n $$
$\forall 1 \leq \Psi \leq \Phi$ and $ n \geq \hat{n} = 1$.

But I am not sure if this argument is correct as the bound I got is $>n^2$ which intuitively seems off since we are taking square root at each step and doing $\log \log n$ work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log x$ definitely satisfies the polynomial growth condition since it is $O(x)$, but the Akra–Bazzi method does not need to be used to solve $S(m)$; the standard master theorem gives $T(2^m)=S(m)=\Theta(m^{\log_25})$ and thus $T(n)=\Theta((\log_2n)^{\log_25})$.

Comment: I use Akra-Bazzi as I find it easier to understand than the Master's theorem. I found my mistake. I forgot to substitute $m$ back in terms of $n$, doing which gives me the same answer as yours. Thanks for clarifying the doubt about growth of $\log$!

Comment: @ParclyTraxel: Sorry for not clarifying this earlier but this is a homework problem, so it would be great if you could hide the answer to the recurrence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\log\equiv \log_2$ and making first $n=2^m$ we have

$$
T(2^m) = 5T(2^{\frac m2})+\log m
$$

or equivalently

$$
R(m) = 5R\left(\frac m2\right)+\log m
$$

and now after $m=2^z$ we have

$$
R(2^z) = 5R(2^{z-1})+z
$$

or equivalently

$$
S(z) = 5 S(z-1) + z
$$

This recurrence has the solution

$$
S(z) = 5^zc_0-\frac{5}{16} \left(\frac{4 z}{5}-5^z+1\right)
$$

going now backwards with $z=\log_2 m$ and $m = \log_2 n$ we arrive at

$$
T(n) = 5^{\log\log n}c_0-\frac{5}{16} \left(\frac{4 \log\log n}{5}-5^{\log\log n}+1\right)
$$

then

$$
T(n) = \mathcal{O}(5^{\log\log n})
$$

Comment: This is equivalent to my answer as $5^{\log\log n} = (\log n)^{\log 5}$ which is what I got. Thanks for giving an alternate way to do it!